# How to fix the background color on "display:table-column"

Tags: css, tablecolumn

How i can fix the background-color height for each column...I have used different background color for each column. If i have added long text in a div than same rows div's background display blank. i need to show the background color there. I have tried height:100%.. but not working. and i cant make height fix in size. Becoz some of the text is very long.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .divTable
  {
    font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;
    display:  table;
    width: 685px;
    border:1px solid  #666666;
    border-spacing:1px;
    /*cellspacing:poor IE support for  this*/
    /* border-collapse:separate;*/
  }
  .headRow
  {
    background:#D8DEEA; 
    display:table-row;
   }
  .divRow
  {
    display:table-row;
    width:auto;
  }
  .bgColorGray
  {
    background:#ccc;
  }
  .bgColorf2
  {
    background:#E0E0E0;
  }
  .bgColorEA
  {
    background:#EAE9E9;
  }
  .bgColorf5
  {
    background:#f5f5f5;
  }
  .divCell
  {
    float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
    display:table-column;
    width:150px;
    padding: 10px;
    height:100%;
  }
  .divCellTitle
  {
    float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
    display:table-column;
    width:150px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
</style>

<div class="divTable">
<div class="headRow">
    <div class="divCellTitle">Company</div>
    <div class="divCellTitle">Q1</div>
    <div class="divCellTitle">Q2</div>
    <div class="divCellTitle">Q3</div>
</div>
<div class="divRow ieclear">
    <div class="divCell bgColorGray">Microsoft</div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorf2"></div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorEA">50.2</div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorf5">30.2</div>
</div>
<div class="divRow ieclear">
    <div class="divCell bgColorGray">Google</div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorf2">30.2</div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorEA">50.2</div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorf5">Test Line Test Line Test lien line two </div>
</div>
<div class="divRow ieclear">
    <div class="divCell bgColorGray">Microsoft</div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorf2"></div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorEA">50.2</div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorf5">30.2</div>
</div>
<div class="divRow ieclear">
    <div class="divCell bgColorGray">Google</div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorf2">30.2</div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorEA">50.2</div>
    <div class="divCell bgColorf5">Test Line Test Line Test lien line two </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think u may like this http://tinkerbin.com/Jovo6sH3

Comment: The data you are displaying is really tabular data which is what the html table element is still supposed to be used for. If you switch to a table it should be much easier to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes i know, it will be more easy if i use html table. But i need to do it in DIV only...:) and Thanks :) Rohit Its working.. but need to fix in IE7...:(

Comment: Why do you need to do it with `DIV` only?

Comment: Becoz my team-lead wants to make it in div only...

Comment: Rohit Azad modified my css.. and its working fine in FF, Chrome, IE8,9.. but not working in IE7...:(

Comment: Then convince your teamleader that it is folly, since the `<table>` is made for, that's right, tabular data. The exact thing you are presenting. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Hey Rohit, Can plz help me to make it working ie7 also????